# SQL Server Switching Between IS NULL and = in same statement

Tags: sql-server

```
Snip..
    WHERE     (dbo.ProductIngredients.Ing_EffectiveTo =
                              (SELECT     TOP (1) Ing_EffectiveTo
                                FROM          dbo.ProductIngredients AS ProductIngredients_1
                                WHERE      (Ing_Id = dbo.ProductIngredients.Ing_Id)
                                ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Ing_EffectiveTo IS NULL THEN '01/01/2050' ELSE Ing_EffectiveTo END) DESC))
```

This works fine is the from the sub where clause is not null, however when null it obviously fails unless I mess with ansi_null settings (which we wont be able to do in next version of sql server so looking for better way). How can I make this query work its like I have to change from = to IS based on the result

Answer (score 4):

Can't you use `ISNULL(Ing_EffectiveTo,'01/01/2050'`) ?

Comment: Nope because I dont know weather the value return is NULL or Not, if its not null I want to match against that value..

Comment: @mattcodes, If it's null you want it to use '01/01/2050' right?

Comment: Initially the 01/01/2050 replacement is to ensure that a null value is consider a future data rather than a previous data. but used same technique in coalesce and all well now

Comment: okay, but as I understand you ISNULL should be perfect for you. If Ing_EffectiveTo is null then choose the date in the future, otherwise use Ing_EffectiveTo.

Comment: @Arkain: My understanding is that ISNULL and COALESCE do the same thing, but COALESCE is standard SQL.

Comment: @Justin K, yes they are similar, but there are some differences: http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/coalesce-vs-isnull-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it just wrapped COALESCE around both parts using 01/01/2050. This allows me to use = with NULL - incase where I dont know if value is null or not (and I care about the value if not null) - Legacy DB.

Comment: the `isnull` mentioned in the other answer is exactly what you need.. But you should only use it in the `order by` section

Comment: Nope, Im interesting in selecting either the latest effective date (which is null) or failing that the most recent date over a set of ingredients. Its not a boolean case of is null or not.

Comment: I still don't understand how isnull can't do this for you, can you give us an example of some data, and what you expect to get back?